# setTimeout global variable

Tags: settimeout

```
var delayTime = 2000;
for(var i = 0; i<this.textToWrite.length; i++){
  setTimeout(
    (
      function (s){
        return function () {
          this.writeText += s;
          console.log(this.writeText);
        }
      }(this.textToWrite[i])
    ), delayTime)
  delayTime += 2000;
}
```

have some problem with *this.writeText*. It's global variable but when i even comment *+= s* line then i have undefined value... (I set writeText: string = "" globaly)  Is *this.writeText* reference to global variable? How can I access global variables in this example? 
I need assing char from textToWrite object to writeText with 2s delay.

Comment: Did you difined textToWrite, and writeText globally like delayTime ? and what output you are looking for?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be that you used function word.

```
setTimeout(
((s) => {
    return () => {
      this.writeText += s;
      console.log(this.writeText);
    }
  }(this.textToWrite[i])
), delayTime)
```

Another way is to use it without this if its global variable:

```
 setTimeout(
((s) => {
    return () => {
      writeText += s;
      console.log(this.writeText);
    }
  }(this.textToWrite[i])
), delayTime)
```

Comment: You are welcome. Have a Great day :-)

Answer (score 0):

Only use arrow functions

```
settimeout(x => {
   console.log(x);
}, 1000);
```

not like this and it will not accept out side parameters

```
settimeout(funtion(x) {
   console.log(x);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: your right, thank you friendoo